# Does a $k$-derivation of $k[G]$ into $k$ induce an element of $k[G]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $k$, and let $e$ be the identity of $G$.  Then $k$ is a $k[G]$-module via the action $f \cdot a = f(e)a$.  The tangent space of $G$ at $e$ can be identified with the $k[G]$-module $\textrm{Der}_k(k[G],k)$, where $k$ in the second argument is regarded as a $k[G]$-module.  So every $f \in k[G]$ is associated with an element $\delta(f) \in k$.

There is supposed to be (Humphreys, Linear Algebraic Groups) an injective homomorphism of $k$-vector spaces $$\eta: \textrm{Der}_k(k[G],k) \rightarrow \textrm{Der}_k(k[G],k[G])$$ given by the formula $$\eta(\delta)(f)(x) = \delta(\lambda_{x^{-1}}(f))$$ where $\lambda_{x^{-1}}$ is the $k$-algebra automorphism of $k[G]$ given by $\lambda_{x^{-1}}(h)(y) = h(xy)$.  *What I don't understand is why the assignment $x \mapsto \delta(\lambda_{x^{-1}}f)$ actually defines an element of $k[G]$, i.e. a regular function from $G$ to $k$.*

Here is a very simple example.  Let $G = k$, so $k[G] = k[X]$.  Let $\delta: k[X] \rightarrow k$ be the $k$-derivation given by $\delta(f(X)) = f'(0)$.  Then $\eta(\delta): k[G] \rightarrow k[G]$ is the function $$\eta(\delta)(f(X))(x) = \delta(\lambda_{-x}f(X)) = \delta(f(X-x)) = f'(-x)$$ and the mapping $x \mapsto f'(-x)$ is certainly regular.

Comment: I think what is going on here is one is constructing a vector field on $G$ (an element of Der(k[G] to k[G]) ) by taking a tangent vector and translating it around $G$. You might want to check Mumford's Abelian Varieties 96-98 for another exposition of this.